# Why I am getting this ASM Tool error as error no valid device found and could not open device?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created 2 raw partition in my computer so that I can install Oracle 11g grid but before I have to use asm tool for automatic storage management but its not happening it is showing error codes ASM-00001, ASM-00203. So, if anyone knows how to solve it please tell me it will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

[Here is the screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYaUG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> #### ASM-0001: could not open device \?\volume...
>
> O/S-Error: (OS-5) Access is denied.
>   **Cause:** User Account Control (UAC), a new security component in Windows Server 2008 and later releases can require administrators to specifically approve administrative actions or applications before they are allowed to run. If you do not supply the proper credentials, the asmtool and asmtoolg utilities report these errors.
>
> **Action:** There are a few ways to resolve this problem:
>   Click Continue in the UAC dialog box if you are logged in as an administrative user, or provide the credentials for an administrator user, then click Continue.
>
> Create a desktop shortcut to a command window. Open the command window using the Run as Administrator option, then right-click the context menu, and launch asmtool.
>
> Configure the UAC implementation on your Windows Server to turn off UAC or to change the elevation prompt behavior for administrator users.

This error is well documented in [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e48194/trouble.htm#CWWIN414).

Comment: Sir, even after following your action AsmTool still showing the same error.